# The preview for a question is different from the view of the question

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, blockquote

This is not a duplicate of [Block quote handling mismatch between preview and post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376196/block-quote-handling-mismatch-between-preview-and-post). The questions are somewhat similar in that the preview is incorrectly parsing the Markdown, but from both a programming and CommonMark specification perspective they describe different issues. The differences between the two questions are:

- This question shows the preview incorrectly recognizing "2. Second Point" as a new list when the [CommonMark specification explicitly says](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items) a new list must begin with 1 there. Specifically:

  > When the first list item in a [list](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list) interrupts a paragraph—that is, when it starts on a line that would otherwise count as [paragraph continuation](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#paragraph-continuation-text) text—then (a) the lines Ls must not begin with a blank line, and (b) if the list item is ordered, the start number must be 1.
- The [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376196/block-quote-handling-mismatch-between-preview-and-post) shows the preview thinking that the "702.151b" line is a new quoteblock when the [CommonMark specification explicitly says](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#block-quotes) that's not possible to have a second quote block without a blank line. Specifically:

  > 3. **Consecutiveness.** A document cannot contain two [block quotes](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#block-quotes) in a row unless there is a [blank line](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#blank-line) between them.

Both questions deal with the class of issues of the preview recognizing paragraph continuation text, but are different issues.

---

The preview for a question is different from the view of the question\

Example:

1. First Point

> First Quote
> 2. Second Point
> Second Quote

The preview looks like:

[image]

The question looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block quote handling mismatch between preview and post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376196/block-quote-handling-mismatch-between-preview-and-post) - found using a [site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=preview+different+block+quote). Note the other question deals with a second level quote, but the cause is quite likely the same, or at least closely related, since the problem there is the same as yours, i.e., what shows as 2 quotes in the preview ends up as being just one quote in the final post display.

Comment: That question talks about second-level blockquote formatting, this is first level. Plus, its been a year and looks like no action has been taken.

Comment: Stack Exchange really doesn't do example questions. If you really need *somewhere else* to put an example, then you could use the "[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/271271)". However, the code/Markdown you're having an issue with should really go in *this question*, so you're not requiring people to go elsewhere to see the actual code.

Comment: @Makyen I'm not exactly sure it's the same backend issue that's causing the problem. In the other issue, there's no text in between the two blockquotes, whereas here, there's text. As such, I'm moving to leave this open. If it indeed turns out to be so, staff can close it.

Comment: @JohnOmielan See above.

Comment: @whoisit Keep in mind that in general, "this issue has been previously reported but remained unhandled for a long time" is not an acceptable rationale for a new report. The team prefers that reports for the same issue be consolidated in one report - with the sole exception being regressions, or bugs that were *previously fixed* but have come up again.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm also not sure if the cause is the same for both problems, as my original comment indicates, but I am reasonably certain that it is, or at least they are related closely enough that fixing one issue will involve fixing the other one as well. Thus, I believe it's better to instead consider this question to be a duplicate by default, with the staff reopening this question (ideally with an answer indicating the problem has been fixed) if it turns out otherwise.

Comment: @JohnOmielan That will reduce the chance that the question will actually get seen by a staff member and get fixed. From what I've seen, they tend to ignore closed questions when looking for pending reports.

Comment: Looking at these again, @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog is correct, these are not the same issue. [Well, OK, they are the same *class* of issue, but they aren't the same.] In this instance, the backend is wrong in applying laziness to continue the blockquote through the two ordered lists, when the spec is that laziness should only apply to paragraph continuation text, not to something that should be a new block (such as a list). [Of note is that "2. Second Point" is invalid there and neither implementation gets it right, as ordered list items that interrupt a paragraph must start with the number 1]

Comment: Whereas, in [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376196/block-quote-handling-mismatch-between-preview-and-post) the preview gets it wrong and the backend gets it correct. The "702.151b" line is definitely paragraph continuation text and does not constitute a new blockquote. In fact, the spec explicitly says "[**Consecutiveness.** A document cannot contain two block quotes in a row unless there is a blank line between them.](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#block-quotes)"

Comment: @Makyen To clarify your ending note in your first of two comments above, CommonMark doesn't support generating `<ol start="[x]">` elements where `[x]` is a number greater than 1?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm still unsure how likely they involve the same issue, but I believe you're correct that being considered a duplicate will reduce the chances that this question will be appropriately handled, even if the other question is later fixed (& possibly also answered). In addition, Makyen's explanation indicates the differences between the 2 questions are possibly more than what I initially considered. As such, I've retracted my close vote, but I'm leaving my earlier comments, so anybody reading the set of comments will fully understand their context.

Comment: NOTE: In my above comment regarding "In this instance" I read the image included here in the question incorrectly. Now that I see the example text actually in the question, it's clear the backend is doing things correctly by consolidating "First Quote 2. Second Point Second Quote" into a single paragraph in the (only) blockquote, because lists are not permitted to interrupt paragraphs with any starting number other than "1", so the line of "2. Second Point" is, in fact, paragraph continuation text, so should be in the "First Quote" and making one single quote block.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That's not what I said. CommonMark [doesn't permit lists to *interrupt a paragraph* with any start number other than 1](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#list-items). If the list isn't interrupting a paragraph (e.g. add a blank line before the list), then it can have any starting number you want, within the range of acceptable start numbers (i.e. between 1 to 9 digits (0-9)).

Comment: More succinctly, the differences between the two questions are: This question shows the preview incorrectly recognizing "2. Second Point" as a new list when the CommonMark spec explicitly says a new list must begin with 1 there. The [other question](/questions/376196/block-quote-handling-mismatch-between-preview-and-post) shows the preview thinking that the "702.151b" line is a new quoteblock when the CommonMark spec explicitly says that's not possible without a blank line. Both questions deal with the class of issues of the preview recognizing paragraph continuation text, but are different.

Comment: See also: From the announcement: ["This isn’t currently CommonMark compliant but we’re working on improving it."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/282094), https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280148/282094 and similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367621/282094

Comment: Yes, the preview is making a different guess to the posted answer, but it's because the syntax is poor. If you get your syntax right, it does it properly. See my answer under the duplicate link. SE doesn't like trying to create lists or quotes if the line separations are not done properly.